# node.js SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in Version v0.10.43

Tags: javascript, node.js

I habe the following line of code in my js file:

```
const { connectDb } = require("./db");
```

When I run nodejs locally everthing is fine and I dont get an error.

Im using v10.16.0 locally. When I put that on a server, I got the follwoing error:

```
2019-07-23 15:49:36.925754500 const { connectDb } = require("./db");
2019-07-23 15:49:36.925779500       ^
2019-07-23 15:49:36.930604500 SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
2019-07-23 15:49:36.930606500     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
2019-07-23 15:49:36.930607500     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2019-07-23 15:49:36.930608500     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2019-07-23 15:49:36.930609500     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2019-07-23 15:49:36.930610500     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
2019-07-23 15:49:36.930611500     at startup (node.js:119:16)
2019-07-23 15:49:36.930612500     at node.js:945:3
```

I'm running Version v0.10.43 on that server. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you run this old version on server?

Comment: That's a pretty ancient version of Node, and it doesn't support destructuring inititializations.

Comment: You need to upgrade the nodejs version on the server because on version v0.10.43  destructuring initialization not supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm running Version v0.10.43 on that server. What am I doing wrong?

You're running v0.10.43.

Is it too old to support [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (which was added in 6.0.0 … which is *also* past end of life!).

You could replace it with:

```
const connectDb = require("./db").connectDb
```

… but are likely to run into other problems down the line.

v0.10.43 is from 2013. It is over half a decade old. It is past the end of life. It is not supported. It does not get security releases. Don't use it.

Use [a supported version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js#Releases) instead.